# How to get input for arrays whose length is not determined

Tags: c, arrays

I am supposed to write a program that "quicksort"s a given array of numbers. The problem is , dynamic memory allocation is not allowed and nor am I given the number of "numbers" that are supposed to be inputs of my program.

For instance, here's an input/output example:

INPUT: 0 1 5 3 6 2 4

OUTPUT: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

But I just can't seem to be able to close my while loop when getting the numbers using scanf(); (I know , scanf() is silly , but I can't use "iostream" either)

Here's the code I was trying to get to work:

```
int main()
{
    int target_arr[1000], l, h, i = 0, c = 0, k = 0;
    while (scanf("%d", &target_arr[i]) != EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }
    h = i -1;
    l = 0;
    quick(l, h, target_arr);
    print_arr(target_arr, i );
    return 0;
}
```

quick() and print_arr() functions are previously defined and work perfectly well given the proper input.I just don't know how to stop the loop when I'm done inputting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: press CTRL + D (on *nix)

Comment: press CTRL + Z (on Windows console)

Comment: or have a special "end of input token", like -99999, and if the input equals that, exit your loop

Comment: write the input in a text and use '<' to direct it to your program.
Such as: ./my_program < my_input

Comment: Is the input all in one line?

Comment: Or you could type an alphabet character to end the input (say Q) and change the loop to `while(scanf("%d", &target_arr[i]) == 1)`.

Comment: @kabanus yes, just as explained in example

Comment: @WeatherVane That is simply not an option , since I'm not the one designing the test cases. The program should work as per the given examples, that is , all numbers in a line and that's it. It doesn't even explain whether the array of numbers is finished with a \n or \0 or anything. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: In that case you could read the line with `fgets` and walk through the string yourself, or apply `strtok`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm kinda new , here would you please explain a bit more?Also , this particular structure that I've written , passes 3 test cases out of 10, and for the other 7 it exceeds the time limit.

Comment: The `fgets` will end at EOF or `newline`, whichever comes first. I don't now understand you though, if you say the program passes some test cases, then it must have detected EOF.

Comment: @WeatherVane I just noticed that if I input my array and then type in ctrl+z+enter three times, the program stops, but why?

Comment: Curious indeed, I get that too, but when I try `getchar` or `fgets` it only requires a single `Ctrl-Z` and `Enter`.